# Sql Server Count columns where columns to the right are blank

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

sorry about the confusing title, I couldn't think of a more clear way to explain this!
I have a table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  status1   |   status2  |   status3  |   status4  |   status5  | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2012-02-27 | 2012-11-19 |    NULL    |    NULL    |    NULL    |
| 2  | 2012-03-27 | 2012-11-19 |    NULL    |    NULL    |    NULL    |
| 3  | 2013-06-10 | 2013-06-10 | 2013-08-16 |    NULL    |    NULL    |
| 4  | 2013-06-10 | 2013-06-10 |    NULL    | 2013-08-16 |    NULL    |
| 5  | 2013-07-16 | 2013-07-16 | 2013-08-16 |    NULL    |    NULL    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And what I  want to do is count the number of values in each column where there are no more values in the columns to the right.  In this case, the results should look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  status1   |   status2  |   status3  |   status4  |   status5  | 
------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |      2     |      2     |      1     |      0     |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is track the progress of an order and figure out what status it is currently at.  Whichever is the last status to be populated is the status that row is in.

My SQL is basic, can anyone help me achieve this?  In reality there are 10 statuses and you cannot simply look for the highest date in each row because an order may progress through multiple status in a single day.

Thanks for any help!  I'll bet there's a fairly simple solution to this but I can't get there on my own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT,STATUS1 DATE, STATUS2  DATE,   STATUS3 DATE, STATUS4 DATE, STATUS5 DATE)
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES 
(1,'2012-02-27','2012-11-19',   NULL     ,   NULL   ,NULL),
(2,'2012-03-27','2012-11-19',   NULL     ,   NULL   ,NULL),
(3,'2013-06-10','2013-06-10','2013-08-16',   NULL   ,NULL),
(4,'2013-06-10','2013-06-10',   NULL     ,'2013-08-16',NULL),
(5,'2013-07-16','2013-07-16','2013-08-16',   NULL   ,NULL)
```

Query:

```
SELECT  COUNT([1]) STATUS1,
        COUNT([2]) STATUS2,
        COUNT([3]) STATUS3,
        COUNT([4]) STATUS4,
        COUNT([5]) STATUS5
FROM    
(
SELECT  ID,ISNULL(STATUS5,ISNULL(STATUS4,ISNULL(STATUS3,ISNULL(STATUS2,STATUS1)))) X 
FROM    (
        SELECT  ID,
                CASE WHEN STATUS1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END STATUS1,
                CASE WHEN STATUS2 IS NOT NULL THEN 2 ELSE NULL END STATUS2,
                CASE WHEN STATUS3 IS NOT NULL THEN 3 ELSE NULL END STATUS3,
                CASE WHEN STATUS4 IS NOT NULL THEN 4 ELSE NULL END STATUS4,
                CASE WHEN STATUS5 IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE NULL END STATUS5
        FROM    @TAB
        )LU)LU2 PIVOT (SUM(X) FOR X IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) PIV
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| status1   | status2   | status3   | status4   | status5   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     0     |    2      |    2      |    1      |    0      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for this, decided to mark this as the best answer as it was the easiest to understand and adapt into my existing SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

```
;With MyCTE AS
(
SELECT 'Status' + COALESCE 
       (
           CASE WHEN NOT status5 IS NULL THEN '5' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status4 IS NULL THEN '4' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status3 IS NULL THEN '3' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status2 IS NULL THEN '2' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status1 IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE NULL END,
           '0'
       ) AS Col
FROM Table1
)
SELECT Col, COUNT(*)
FROM MyCTE
GROUP BY Col
```

**[SQL FIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2eedb/1)**

This will get your result in rows. After that you can `PIVOT` to get what you want.

```
;With MyCTE AS
(
SELECT 'Status' + COALESCE 
       (
           CASE WHEN NOT status5 IS NULL THEN '5' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status4 IS NULL THEN '4' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status3 IS NULL THEN '3' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status2 IS NULL THEN '2' ELSE NULL END,
           CASE WHEN NOT status1 IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE NULL END,
           '0'
       ) AS Col
FROM Table1
)
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT Col
           FROM   MyCTE
       ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT  (
           COUNT(Col)
           FOR Col IN ([status1], [status2], [status3], [status4], [status5])
       ) AS PivotTable;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2eedb/4)**

Comment: Thanks for that, but is the fiddle returning the correct results?  It's bringing back 1 - 2 - 2 - 1 when it should be 0 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 0

Comment: The results are correct. Check the column names. Also check my update in a few as i have the pivot ready for you.

Comment: Thanks for the example, decided to choose the other suggestion as the correct answer as I found this a bit harder to implement.  I had existing SQL which I'd already used to get other data into the format I described in the examples and that, along with my column names being different to those used in this example and your code seeming to rely on that, I couldn't get this to work.  Thanks for your efforts though.